# How to run a specific job using Maven command in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-batch

Given you have this job configuration below, how can you execute the job `scrubWord` in command line in a Spring Boot - Spring Batch application using Maven command?

```java
@Configuration
public class WordConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    WordReader wordReader;

    @Autowired
    WordProcessor wordProcessor;

    @Autowired
    WordWriter wordWriter;

    @Bean
    public Job scrubWords() {
        Step scrubWords = stepBuilders
                .get("scrubWord")
                .<Set<String>, Set<String>>chunk(1)
                .reader(wordReader)
                .processor(wordProcessor)
                .writer(wordWriter)
                .build();
        return jobBuilders.get("wordScrubber")
                .start(scrubWords)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Inside file `application.properties` add

```java
spring.batch.job.names=wordScrubber
```

If you have many jobs

```java
spring.batch.job.names=wordScrubber,foo,bar
```

then run

```java
mvn spring-boot:run
```

**Solution 2:** Best practice way is

```java
$ java -jar myapp.jar --server.port=7070 someParameter=someValue
```

Not use Maven parameter, use parameter when run JAR file. See reference document at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.batch.running-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.batch.job.names=wordScrubber
```

- `clean` to overwrite previously compiled files in `target/classes`.
- `spring-boot:run` start ups spring boot.
- `-Dspring.batch.job.names=<jobName>` run a specific batch job.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the executable jar as follows

```
java -Dspring.batch.job.names=myJob -jar myjar.jar [job parameters]
```